# Gimp: Can't use fill bucket to fill selection

Tags: gimp

I have a small image file (a .gif file containing
[image] ) with a transparent background and some small red squares in the foreground. I would like to change the foreground colour from red to blue (RGB 0, 0, 255).

I've managed to select the red squares using 'select by colour':

[image]

but I can't figure out how to use the fill bucket to colour them blue. When I hold the fill bucket cursor over the red squares, it displays the cursor which indicates I can apply the foreground colour, but when I click, nothing happens.

I'm missing something obvious. What is it?

Comment: You are using indexed coulor, is blue one of them?

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure what you mean by 'indexed colour'? (Although I notice it now in the Gimp window title, which I hadn't spotted before.)

Comment: Your file has a limited set of specific colors (reading form the window title). If you want to use other colors, first change the mode to rgb. (Image > Mode translated from Dutch)

Comment: Ok, I did that, and now it works! Thanks. Feel free to add this as an answer.

Comment: You're more then welcome :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your window title, you are working in "indexed colour" mode, which means your file has a limited colour palette. This saves space, and is why these files take very little memory to load.

If you want to edit the file, with all colours available, you should first switch to `RGB` mode, else the colour simply isn't available in your file :)

[image]

Comment: Did you eagle eyes? =)

Comment: @A.B. I noticed on my screen, looking from my kitchen :)

Comment: Could you please detail the steps necessary to reproduce this solution in English please?

Comment: @aviggiano replaced the image.